How to configure Ubuntu 24.04 custom storage layout

So is this correct approach? or do i increase the /boot/efi to larger?
I dont need SWAP to be that big, i only need SWAP to be 16GB since i
have 256GB memory server.

I have 1 250GB SSD and 1.6TB NVME and i want to make the 250GB SSD handle all things OS so the server can boot from it and want the NVME to handle everything else after that, so i can replace the NVMe and still have my OS working fine
I currently have this storage configuration layout and wanted to check if this is correct way to approach this while achieving the above of the SSD as OS drive and NVME and everything else
ubuntu-24-04-lts:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            13G  2.0M   13G   1% /run
efivarfs        192K  133K   55K  72% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p1  1.5T  2.4G  1.4T   1% /
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       1.1G  6.2M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs            13G   12K   13G   1% /run/user/1000

ubuntu-24-04-lts:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2        8:2    0 231.8G  0 part [SWAP]
nvme0n1     259:1    0   1.5T  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0   1.5T  0 part /

What i did is mark the SSD as boot OS drive and automatically the 1G is assigned to /boot/efi and then i made everything else left on the SSD as swap, because i wanted NVME to be / for everything else
So is this correct approach? or do i increase the /boot/efi to larger? I dont need SWAP to be that big, i only need SWAP to be 16GB since i have 256GB memory server.
when i perform kernel upgrades, where will those be saved? will i run out of space on the OS drive with this setup?
Thanks

Your /boot/efi is using 6.2 MB out of 1.1GB; you could even resize it to less space, don't worry about it. Kernel initial images are stored at /boot and kernel modules at /usr/lib/modules. If it's useful to you to have an aprox idea, my Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 with base and 2 additional kernel upgrades uses at /boot 285MB(~60-70MB/kernel img) and at /usr/lib/modules 834MB(~300+300+230). What do you want to store at removable nvmes?Because if you just have /boot/efi at ssd and the rest at nvme, as that prompt shows, if you plug other different you won't have OS to use I guess

actually you are right, i may need to use /nvme for the NVMe drive and reduce swap to 16GB on SSD so that way the rest will be mounted at / for SSD
then if i remove NVME, OS works fine still. So my current layout will not work. thanks for letting me see this
